# FEN notation problem

Tags: fen

See image: [image]Why does this FEN code display incorrectly (it should describe the Portsmouth gambit)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK I seem to have solved this. In the .fen file do not use pgn tags!
Then the FEN code displays correctly. Of course FEN positions can be added or used in PGN files and then the pgn tags are needed[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT2Lc.jpg)

See image..hope this may help others